# htaccess RewriteBase not working

Tags: .htaccess

For development, I have my site setup in a subdirectory called "staging". All the JS and CSS references are pointing to /css/styles.css for example (notice the / before css).

The problem that occurs is when I am in a directory such as /staging/contact/ the contact page tried to load "/staging/contact/css/styles.css" rather it should be loading in "/staging/css/styles.css".

I have tried to rewritebase via htaccess however it's not working. I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /staging/
```

When I view the source on the contact page (as it's not loading in any CSS/JS) it is still referencing /staging/contact/css/styles.css. What have I done wrong here? :/

Answer (score 2):

Place this code in your **`DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` (a level above /staging/)**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/staging/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|ico|png|tiff|css|js)$ /staging%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

Then no need to change your css/JS URLs and no need to use `<BASE>` tag in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your scripts and styles are probably linked using relative URI's. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

You need to add a base to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/staging/" />
```

Or, if neither of those are an option, you can try adding an additional rewrite rule to the top of your htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /staging/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(css|js)/([^/]+)\.(js|css)$ $2/$3.$4 [R=301,L]
```

the htaccess file that is in staging.

Comment: Thanks @JonLin - I prefer htaccess but it's still not working? :/

Comment: Thanks @JonLi but it's still not working, with either the base href or rewritebase (which I prefer). Any idea what it may be?

Comment: @DT.DTDG where is the htaccess file located?

Comment: /var/www/sub.domain.com/staging/

Comment: @DT.DTDG sorry, 2 more things. The `$2/$3` doesn't need the `/` in front because of the base. Also, if you want to use the `<base>` tag, your css limks need to be relative, so that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll give your updated answer a go now. Yup, I'm keeping them absolute.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39038/discussion-between-dt-dtdg-and-jon-lin)